# Flask session doesn't persist in cypress test

Tags: session, cypress

Flask application consisting of login and form **works well manually**. However **in Cypress** test session is not available and **test fails**. Any idea how to solve or debug this behavior?

I can see create project form displayed.

I can see Cypress test click on the "Create" button.

Then manual test displays expected message that project was created.

However automatic cypress test behaves as if session doesn't exist

app.py

```
@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    user = session.get('user')
    return render_template('home.html', user=user)

@app.route('/login-test/<string:email_address>/')
def logintest(email_address):
    if (app.debug):
        userid = 1
        user = { "email" : email_address, "uid" : userid }
        session['user'] = user
    else:
        flash("debug is off, can't use testlogin")
    return redirect('/')

@app.route('/create-project/', methods=['POST'])
def createproject():
    user = session.get('user')
    if (user):
        flash("Project added successfully")        
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        flash("Session not found")
        return redirect('/')
```

templates/home.html

```
{% if user %}
<form action="create-project" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter new project name">
    <input type="submit" value="Create">
</form>
<a href='/logout'>destroy session</a>
{% else %}
<a href='/login'>login</a>
{% endif %}
```

cypress test:

```
describe('Basic tests', () => {
    it('We will use test login to login user1', () => {
        cy.visit('/login-test/user1@test.cz/')
        cy.contains('destroy session')
    }),
    it('We can create project', () => {
        cy.get('input[placeholder="Enter new project name"]').type('ProjectNo1')       
        cy.get('input[value="Create"]').click().contains('Project added successfully')
    })
})
```

Comment: Do you know how flask persists the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cypress cleans session between tests and in order to preserve session cookie I need to add

```
Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('session')
```

after

```
cy.contains('destroy session')
```

See: https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cookies#Preserve-Once

Ravikiran on discord cypress channel helped me with this.